# Parse personal name and job title out of string

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I am trying to parse out the job title and personal name out of some text from an OCR scan.

String:      `841 l5          )“-~_§' ‘Ir-‘P...   Dennis Hadley Account Manager`

As you can see there is some garbage text which I think is OK.

Here is how I tried to go about parsing the personal name out of the string:

```
  NSString *question = @"     841 l5          )“-~_§' ‘Ir-‘P...   Dennis Hadley Account Manager  ";
        NSLinguisticTaggerOptions options = NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames;
        NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes: [NSLinguisticTagger availableTagSchemesForLanguage:@"en"] options:options];
        tagger.string = question;
        [tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [question length]) scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass options:options usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString *token = [question substringWithRange:tokenRange];
            NSLog(@"%@: %@", token, tag);
        }];
```

Here is the output:

```
2014-04-20 17:32:54.349 NameDetection[7126:303] 841: Number
2014-04-20 17:32:54.349 NameDetection[7126:303] l5: Number
2014-04-20 17:32:54.350 NameDetection[7126:303] ~: Noun
2014-04-20 17:32:54.350 NameDetection[7126:303] Ir: Noun
2014-04-20 17:32:54.350 NameDetection[7126:303] P: Noun
2014-04-20 17:32:54.351 NameDetection[7126:303] Dennis Hadley Account Manager: PersonalName
```

As you can see it joins the job title and name into one can anyone provide suggestions on how to parse this information out of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is real hard to say. As someones name can contains 2,3 or 4 or even more parts. As you don't have any separator between the name and designation. One idea is as follow.

1. Try to gather all the designation available.
2. Parse that part of string that contains name and designation.
3. Compare the designation with the collected list and parse accordingly to get the name of the employee.

Hope this helps.. :)